# When adding or removing items to cart, it takes cart 30 seconds to 1 minute to update?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a basic cart page. When I add products and move to cart it shows the cart is empty. A few refreshes for 30 seconds to 1 minute and the items are there. When I remove items from the cart it shows the items even though I removed them (sometimes the price in navbar cart updates), and then after a few seconds they are gone. What is causing this issue?

Comment: Are all of your plugins updated? What actions did you take last on your site that caused this unexpected behavior?

Comment: I've disabled most of the plugins , I have a child theme , and I tried disabling it and activating parent but still same issue .

Comment: why down voted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was occurring due to a `footnotes` plugin , when deactivated the problem is solved ,

I tried a couple more `footnotes` plugins same issue re-occur .

hope that helps .